# Aggregate excluding inf

Tags: r

Wondering if someone has a solution for aggregating and excluding Inf values.  For instance

```
df <- data.frame(Id = c(1:9),
         Fact = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
         Values = c(10, 5, 14, 3, 1, 10/0, 7, 11, 22))
```

Notice that Values for Id 6 is Inf

Trying this, notice that the maxvalues for Fact B will be Inf

```
maxvalues <- aggregate(Values~Fact,df,max, na.rm=TRUE)
maxvalues
```

Would like the maxvalues for Fact B to be 3 (which would be the value excluding the Inf).  Hoping to stick with base R if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an anonymous function with a condition on `x`:

```
aggregate(Values ~ Fact, df, function(x) max(x[x < Inf], na.rm = TRUE))
#   Fact Values
# 1    A     14
# 2    B      3
# 3    C     22
```

Or remove those rows prior to aggregation:

```
aggregate(Values ~ Fact, df[df$Values < Inf, ], max, na.rm = TRUE)
#   Fact Values
# 1    A     14
# 2    B      3
# 3    C     22
```